# What is a simple and reliable C library for working with Excel files?

Tags: c, excel

Well... that's it.

I need something **simple** and **reliable** (doesn't have to have fancy features - I need to write and read text and numbers from Excel cells)

And yes, I would like a **sample "Hello Cell" code**...

What do you recommend?

Comment: If possible Windows and Linux, but if not then just Windows since I want to interact with Excel which is on Windows.

Comment: Excel on Linux, I'd be very suprised to  find it. OpenOffice is there and has a usable interface for C++.... Maybe that's what you'd like to try

Comment: "Cello Hell", that's where all the bad Cellists go and make terrible noises together... :/  I'd have a look at the gnumeric source code, it's probably modular.  If you raise money to pay me $1000 I will fix it up into a library ;)

Comment: I cannot understand why this 'recommend a library' question got 26 upvotes, instead of being closed as off-topic:(  SO is terribly inconsistent..

Comment: @MartinJames It was missed. I clicked on the link from your meta post specifically to close whatever was on the other side.

Comment: @MartinJames This questions is from 2009. It's ancient in Stack Overflow terms, and our criteria for on-topic questions has evolved over time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strongly discouraged.  I'd recommend using a C-friendly format (e.g. CSVs) instead of XLS, or using the new [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx) formats (take your pick on XML and ZIP libraries).

Still, for a quick fix, you could export to quoted CSV and then import using [VBScript](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/msoffice/excel/).  Something like [this](http://ourworld.compuserve.com/homepages/guenter_born/wshbazaar/WSHExcel1.htm), although I'd try to get it to work in VBA first.

Note that this will require a copy of Office, and will not scale well (but you *can* hide the Excel window).

---

I've just found [xlsLib](http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/), so if you really need to write directly in C, give it a go!  Be careful though, because it's very hard to get right, especially if you're writing to already-existing files.

There also exists [LibExcel](http://www.libexcel.com/), but that's C++, so you'd need to compile a wrapper around, or rewrite for C.

---

One final caveat: the reason I didn't search for these at the start is that it's extremely difficult to get right.  I have not used the libraries above, but I suspect they'll break in strange and unusual ways.  I trust you've read [Joel's](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html) take on the Office formats.

Comment: Thanks! You have been very helpful regarding new Open XML format (I didn't know it existed)

Comment: libExcel seems to be the commercial libxl

Comment: other way around, I think

Answer (score 12):

Excel, like other Office products, exports its guts over COM.  This is available for use in C++, VB, C#, and whatever other languages have COM interop -- provided that you're running in Windows and have Excel installed.  (You can't get to COM from plain C.  Whether this is fortunate or unfortunate is up to you.)

COM is a bloody messy pain for unmanaged languages, though.  The following VB:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  ' start or use existing Excel
objExcel.Visible = True                           ' show the window
objExcel.Workbooks.Add                            ' create an empty workbook
```

roughly translates into the following C++:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main() {
    HRESULT hr;
    IDispatch *objExcel, *objWorkbooks;
    CLSID clsid;
    DISPID id, id2;
    DISPPARAMS p;
    VARIANT v;
    TCHAR *name;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = CLSIDFromProgID(_T("Excel.Application"), &clsid);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
            IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID *)&objExcel);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    id2 = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;
    name = _T("Visible");
    hr = objExcel->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &name, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &id);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    VariantInit(&v);
    v.vt = VT_I4;
    v.lVal = 1;
    p.cArgs = 1;
    p.rgvarg = &v;
    p.cNamedArgs = 1;
    p.rgdispidNamedArgs = &id2;
    hr = objExcel->Invoke(id, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
            DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, &p, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    name = _T("Workbooks");
    hr = objExcel->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &name, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &id);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    p.cArgs = 0;
    p.rgvarg = NULL;
    p.cNamedArgs = 0;
    p.rgdispidNamedArgs = NULL;
    hr = objExcel->Invoke(id, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
            DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &p, &v, NULL, NULL);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    objWorkbooks = v.pdispVal;

    name = _T("Add");
    hr = objWorkbooks->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &name, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &id);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    p.cArgs = 0;
    p.rgvarg = NULL;
    p.cNamedArgs = 0;
    p.rgdispidNamedArgs = NULL;
    hr = objWorkbooks->Invoke(id, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
            DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &p, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I admit I didn't google much for this question, but that is what stackoverflow is for :) Seriously, I knew that there will be problems finding this library, but I didn't knew that **no one** has managed to write or read a plain Excel cell with no functions,formatting,just text and numbers.you go UP!

Comment: No wonder C++ is going the way of the Dodo.

Comment: There's a lot you can do with COM, but there's not a lot you *want* to do with COM.

Comment: @kliketa - no, it's not:(

Comment: @dreamlax whatever do you mean?  COM is really simple and the easily-comprehended TLB's are a joy to... . hehe, OK not really:)

Answer (score 3):

A free library, but again this is C++, not C:
[ExcelFormat](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelFormat.aspx)

Comment: I'm currently using it, very easy to integrate and use.

Answer (score 2):

I've a small extension to the stuff ephemient has posted. There's very handy library available with eases the paind with the IDispatch interface.
http://disphelper.sourceforge.net/

It's just one file you add to your  projects but it makes IDispatch programming with C nearly fun ;-)

Comment: looks very interesting, but a little old (2004) project

Comment: Wow, that's really quite useful!  kliketa: doesn't matter how old it is, the underlying COM protocol is still the same.  http://disphelper.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/disphelper/disphelper/samples_c/excel.c?view=markup will still work just fine on the latest Windows and Office versions.

Comment: Well it may be "old", but the COM stuff is older ;-) and changes are not to be expected. The helper will just work...

Comment: Still works in 2017...

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [libxlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter), a C library for *writing* Excel XLSX files. However, it can't *read* Excel files and it doesn't support XLS files.