# How read .xls file with cpp in linux

Tags: c++, linux, excel, xls

how read .xls file with cpp in linux ?, i found [this library libxls](http://libxls.sourceforge.net/) but is for C , and found others but not free.

Comment: C is a subset of C++, so libxls should work in your C++ program.

Comment: but in c compile and in cpp not, i got [this](http://pastebin.com/2bLmG2si)

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583776/open-and-read-excel-from-a-linux-based-c-program

Comment: `c` isn't a subset of `c++`, but they're close. Compile with `g++` (which can compile `c` code too) and see if that works.

Comment: `c` isn't a subset of `c++`, this is a big true. :) . i try with `g++` and got the same

Comment: i see the related questions, but i not found one solution, for read .xls and free on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use libxls and made a mix with c and c++ code:

`//my c++ code`

```
 extern "C" {
   #include "xls.h"
 }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

the file format is documented here if you would like to write your own parser for it

http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?search=xls&button=GO%21

Comment: i cant view any info in this site :( , and your answer means no library exists ? or a more easy way that make own parser ?

Comment: hmm, might be temporarily down, that site is where i usually get all my file format docs from. and I have no idea about the existence of such a library, was just providing you with an alternative option if you cannot find one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [Excel Format](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library) lib, which works on windows and linux. It's got some caveats but if you're looking for some basic functionalities that should get you going.