# Read cells from Excel in C++?

Tags: c++, excel, fstream

I was wondering how you can read specific cells from an Excel spreadsheet, in C++. I understand we have to use the "fstream" library, but I don't know exactly how I could get those values from a certain cell, and print it on the screen. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
Carpetfizz

Answer (score 3):

in linux you have this free:
http://libxls.sourceforge.net/

in windows you have http://www.libxl.com/ which seems to cost money:

```
Book* book = xlCreateBook();
if(book)
{
    if(book->load(L"example.xls"))
    {
        Sheet* sheet = book->getSheet(0);
        if(sheet)
        {
            const wchar_t* s = sheet->readStr(2, 1);
            if(s) wcout << s << endl;

            double d = sheet->readNum(3, 1);
            cout << d << endl;
        }
    }
```

**I think the best thing to do is to save the files as `.csv` which is more friendly to work with.**

more references:

1. [What is a simple and reliable C library for working with Excel files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493111/what-is-a-simple-and-reliable-c-library-for-working-with-excel-files)
2. [Reading from and writing to Excel files in C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/417270/Reading-from-and-writing-to-Excel-files-in-Cpluspl)

Comment: Thanks! But, the code you gave me can be used without those programs?

Comment: Ah, so you have to have those for these libraries to work.. the program is $200 haha. When you save them as a .csv, can you use standard read/write functions?

Comment: Yes, that's why they're so popular.

Answer (score 1):

Excel versions before Excel 2007 use a proprietary binary format, but Excel 2007 and later versions use XML ([writes Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats)).

[There's also a C++ library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library) for dealing with Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

For writing, use:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexlsx/

For reading, I use:

sourceforge.net/projects/xlsxio/?source=directory

Also, for xlsxio, I wrote an OO wrapper, to make it more friendly for c++ integration. It only supports reading, but you should probable use simplexlsx for writing anyways!

```
#include "XlsxBook.h"
#include "XlsxSheet.h"
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HJu4VOsY8hMnRla2NMOEM3Z2M/view?usp=sharing