# How To Read data from Microsoft Excel File by C++ Program

Tags: c++, excel

now i have some massive data on Excel Sheet, and i need by c++ program to transform this data into text file, to use it later in another thing.

how can i accesses this Excel file, to get data from first attribute and put delimiter and so on??

Comment: What about saving as txt or csv from excel?

Comment: https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally used Microsoft Excel Automation to read from Excel in the applications I develop. Please check the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15837/Accessing-Excel-Spreadsheets-via-C for more information on Excel Automation.

But it seems there are other options as discussed in the following links
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library
[Read cells from Excel in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200809/read-cells-from-excel-in-c)