# How to read a data from excel file and store into variable?

Tags: c++

I want to read a data from excel file and store into variable i also want to read index of excel file.I don't no how to do this.so please show the your example in c++ code.

Comment: See this open project with example implementation - https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt

Comment: please show what you have tried !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel files are quite hard to read with C++.  They are stored as a binary file and need to be properly read and interpreted by your code.

There are libraries out there to do this. Maybe check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13200859/10997590) out

Comment: It's not clear, if OP really means xls/xlsx files. cvs is supported by excel too amongst many other formats

Comment: I visit this post and use this  #include"libxl.h" but my excel file unable to open. 
 code //if (book->load(L"example.xls")){....} and my excel file name is example.xls why it is opening?   can you help me?

Comment: You should update the question with what you have tried so far and show where you're stuck.   Please show your code and how you compile it.