# c++ or java to change value of excel cell

Tags: java, c++

Is there a program out there where I am able to open an excel file, change the value of one cell with the value going n to n+i, save the file and repeat this process?

Doesn't matter what language it is in. Just need it to work. If anyone knows of a program that will do that it would be greatly appreciated.

Best.

Its a list of 1200 tickers that I need to iterated though, the tickers come from another excel database.

Comment: VBA would be the obvious choice - all the Office programs have it

Comment: If you want to have it be Java, there is the Poi library, otherwise, I agree with @Katana24, use VB.  I think the hotkey is Alt-F11, and works in all Office products.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the provided requirements I'd say MS Excel should do the trick.

Comment: i was gonna say that too lol

Answer (score 1):

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493111/what-is-a-simple-and-reliable-c-library-for-working-with-excel-files) should help.  Same question.

[This Link](http://www.gidforums.com/t-4528.html) was provided as an answer to another question as well.

My advice: export from excel to a .csv file and have it either comma or space delimited based on your needs.  Should be as easy as reading in a text file, which can be done in either c++ or java easily, from that point on.  From what I know, working with excel files in c++ is not a fun place to be.

Edit:  Or just use VBA in excel, tutorials are all over the place online.