# Accessing excel sheet through C in linux

Tags: c, excel, ubuntu

I am trying to access a column from an excel document from a C code in Linux. Is there a simple way to do this? There are more than 47000 rows and I want to store the data of particular column into an array of data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use xlsLib library for parsing excel file. You can find more information [here](http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493111/what-is-a-simple-and-reliable-c-library-for-working-with-excel-files)